# How can I remove the gap between the header and the menu?

Tags: css, header

I'd like to make the header rest right on top of the menu at http://wpdallas.com/test any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: CSS issues are not on-topic for this site. Moving to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the padding on the header - currently it's padding: 10px 0. Change it to padding: 10px 0 0 0;

FYI it might be easier to use firebug or a webkit browser (ie chrome - and you right click and inspect element), where you can inspect the element and that usually helps with CSS. Of course, you would need to double check how they look in IE.